# Return nil on `each` method for array

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, return

I want to return `nil` when iterating through a large array. Mainly because I end up having to scroll through dozens of pages of data in my terminal when I want to simply look at my output at the top. This is my current workaround, which works... But I'm looking for something more reusable:

```
array.each_with_index do |element, i|
  puts 'my output'
  break if i == array.count - 1
end
```

Are there any better ways to do this without having to use an index and break out of the array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You mean you don't want to see the result of "each_with_index"? Put a "; nil" after the"end".

Comment: I wanted to avoid having the entire array be returned at the end of `each`, since `each` returns the entire value of the array. But yeah, the `; nil` suggestion does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: That's what I said :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming it's in repl. In this case, I would add `; nil` or similar to the last line and this will be returned in repl.

In your example:

```rb
array.each_with_index do |element, i|
  puts 'my output'
  break if i == array.count - 1
end; nil
```

Comment: Nice. Simple. I was looking to use it with `each`, and not have to use it with `each_with_index`. Your first snippet achieves this. Not the second one.